# StringVar object is treated as string in function called from a tkinter button

Tags: python, tkinter, pycharm

I'm learning python (my first question on StackOverflow!) and have an issue with tkinter. I am using:

- PyCharm Comm. Edition 2023.2.3 on Windows
- Python 3.12
- Tcl/Tk 8.6

I have the following code with a tkinter button that, when clicked, should get the content of the clipboard by using pyperclip and insert it into the object outline.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import pyperclip

def update_outline():
    c = pyperclip.paste()
    outline.set(c)

root = Tk()
content = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12")
content.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
root.geometry('1200x800')

outline = StringVar()
outline_button = ttk.Button(content, text="Paste", command=update_outline)
outline_button.grid(column=1, row=2, sticky=W)
outline_label = ttk.Label(content, textvariable=outline).grid(column=1, row=3, sticky=(W, E))

root.mainloop()
```

The problem is that when I click on the button I obtain the following error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\...\PycharmProjects\Test\main.py", line 133, in update_outline
    outline.set(c)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'set'
```

I've read the documentation and a lot of articles but I was not able to understand the cause of the error. Can someone help?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Weird - this works as expected if I set `c` to a literal string, e.g. `c = 'hello!'`. Gotta do some digging.

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue.

Comment: Update Pcharm 2023.2.4 released 31 October 2023

Comment: Thank you a lot for the support! I updated PyCharm and all libraries, but the problem still persists. It may be some kind of version incompatibility. I'll try another direction for my script